# how to use py3dns for python3?

Tags: python, email-validation

I need to check if email exist or not. I am using py3dns supportable library for python3. There is an error saying

> For check the mx records or check if the email exists you must have installed pyDNS python package

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
```

Comment: did you install `pydns` or `py3dns` ?

Comment: @furas I installed py3dns, pydns is not supportable library for python 3

Comment: I got it need to import DNS

Comment: https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

You must have install py3dns in order to use this package. This [article](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2021/08/how-to-check-if-email-address-is-valid.html) might help you to install the validate_email correctly.

Otherwise, this package is a great tool to check if an email address is valid.

Check this article this might help you.

[check if an Email Address is Valid and Exists With Python](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2021/08/how-to-check-if-email-address-is-valid.html)